# Not able to see the response by executing curl command in OS process sampler of Jmeter

Tags: curl, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

While I am using the curl command

```
curl -s https://www.google.com/
```

through os process sampler in jmeter , I can see the response in ViewResultsTree.

However while running the below command from os process sampler, I can't see anything in the response in ViewResultsTree.The url is our internal one which needs certificate to validate.

```
curl -s -kX GET -H 'Accept: application/json' --cert 'abc.crt:<passphrase>' --key 'abc.key' https://example.com/accounts/12345/statuses
```

The same curl command , If I run from command line( i.e Terminal), I can see the response as json.

Is anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

I did the workaround by embedding curl command inside a shell script and ran the shell script from OS process sampler and it works fine